# when I use a function pointer variables disappear

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

Ok so I am playing around in my spare time trying to build some function libraries for fun, and I'm teaching myself function pointers.  I tried making a binary_search function which looks for the oldest item in an array of items.  I know the algorithm works, I just can't get past this bug.  For some reason when my code entered the function pointer it stops executing and just dies....  I did some testing and the moment my code enters `strvoidcmp`, the two `void *`s I'm feeding it are null...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "algorithms.h"

void generate_array(char (*partial_list)[10]){
    size_t j = 0, i = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < 20; j++){
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){  
            partial_list[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }


    for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        memcpy(partial_list[i], "is there", 9);
    } 
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        memcpy(partial_list[i], "not there", 10);
    }
}

void LMERROR(char *msg){
    fprintf(stderr, msg);
    fflush(stderr);
}

int binary_search_top(void **list, const int size, void *value, int (*compare)(void *, void *)){
    size_t hi = 0;
    size_t lo = 0;
    size_t mid = 0;
    size_t found = 0;

    if(list == NULL){
        LMERROR("NULL found in function binary_search");
        return -1;
    }

    hi = size;
    printf("test: %s\n", (char *)value);
    while(lo < hi){
        mid = ceil((hi - lo) / 2 + lo);
            printf("test: %d\n", mid);
        if(compare(list[mid], value)){
            hi = mid - 1;
                printf("test1\n");
        }else{
            lo = mid;
            found = mid;
            printf("test2\n");
        }
    }
    printf("exiting");
    return found;
}

int strvoidcmp(void *p1, void *p2){
    printf("testing: %s, %s\n", (char *)p1, (char *)p2);
    return strcmp((char *)p1, (char *)p2);
}

int main(){
    int (*compare)(void *, void *);

    char partial_list[20][10];
    const size_t length = 20;
    char value[] = "is there";
    int ret = 0;
    compare = strvoidcmp;
    printf("test: %d\n", ret);
    generate_array(partial_list);
    printf("test: %d\n", ret);
    ret = binary_search_top((void **)partial_list, length, value, compare);
    printf("test: %d\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can assure you a pointer-to-pointer-to-void and a 2D `char[20][10]` are nowhere *close* to compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `partial_list` is not an array of pointers. `binary_search_top()` thus gets an argument that does not conform to what it expects.

To verify that your `binary_search_top()` works the way you have implemented it, pass it something that `binary_search_top()` can actually use.

```
void *partial_list_pointers[20];

for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    partial_list_pointers[i] = partial_list[i];
}
ret = binary_search_top(partial_list_pointers, length, value, compare);
```

With few exceptions, when used in an expression, the name of an array to BLAH will decay to a pointer to BLAH with the value of the address of its first element. For `partial_list`, since it is an array 20 to and array 10 of `char`, it will decay to a pointer to an array 10 of `char`. This is clearly not a pointer to a pointer.

`partial_list_pointers` addresses this by being an array 20 of pointer of `void`. This will decay to a pointer to pointer of `void`, which is exactly what `binary_search_top()` wants in its first argument.

Comment: +1 for the minimal retrofit. Hopefully the OP understands why the `void**` and `char[20][10]` are not synonymous.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I provided additional explanation about the types being incompatible.